# Persisting state when implementing MinHeap with heapq

Tags: python, heap, python-3.5

I'm trying to implement a `StreamingMedian` object to maintain the median through successive calls of `get_median()`. To do so, I've also implemented a `MinHeap` and `MaxHeap` class via the `heapq` module.

I've run into a very odd bug though. For some reason when I run the following commands:

```
print("Before streaming medians", MinHeap(), sep="\t") # is empty

b = StreamingMedian()
b.add_val(5)
b.add_val(100)

assert b.get_median() == 52.5

print("After streaming medians, for MaxHeap", MaxHeap(), sep='\t') # is empty
print("After streaming medians, for MinHeap", MinHeap(), sep='\t') # should be empty
print("After streaming medians, for MinHeap with input", 
      MinHeap([]), sep="\t") # is empty
```

I get the following outputs:

```
Before streaming medians        []
After streaming medians, for MaxHeap    []
After streaming medians, for MinHeap    [100]
After streaming medians, for MinHeap with input []
```

The class implementations can be found below. I'm running this on Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit).

```
import heapq

class MinHeap(object):

    def __init__(self, l=[]):
        self.heap = l
        heapq.heapify(l)

    def peek(self):
        return self.heap[0]

    def pop(self):
        return heapq.heappop(self.heap)

    def push(self, x):
        heapq.heappush(self.heap, x)

    def pushpop(self, x):
        return heapq.heappushpop(self.heap, x)

    def replace(self, x):
        return heapq.heapreplace(self.heap, x)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.heap)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.heap)

class MaxHeap(MinHeap):

    def _invert_sign(self, l):
        return [-1 * a for a in l]

    def __init__(self, l=[]):
        super().__init__(self._invert_sign(l))

    def push(self, x):
        super().push(-1 * x)

    def pushpop(self, x):
        return super().pushpop(-1 * x)
    def replace(self, x):
        return super().replace(-1 * x)

    def pop(self):
        return -1 * super().pop()

    def peek(self):
        return -1 * super().peek()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._invert_sign(self.heap))


class StreamingMedian():

    def __init__(self):
        self.min_heap = MinHeap()
        self.max_heap = MaxHeap()

    def get_median(self):
        min_heap_has_x_more = len(self.min_heap) - len(self.max_heap)
        if min_heap_has_x_more > 0:
            return self.min_heap.peek()
        elif min_heap_has_x_more < 0:
            return self.max_heap.peek()
        else:
            return (self.min_heap.peek() + self.max_heap.peek())/2

    def add_val(self, x):
        if len(self.min_heap) + len(self.max_heap) == 0:
            self.max_heap.push(x)
        else:
            med = self.get_median()
            if x > med:
                self.min_heap.push(x)
                self._ensure_balance()
            elif x < med:
                self.max_heap.push(x)
                self._ensure_balance()
            else:
                self.max_heap.push(x)
                self._ensure_balance()

    def _ensure_balance(self):
        size_diff = len(self.min_heap) - len(self.max_heap)
        if abs(size_diff) > 1:
            if size_diff > 0: # min_heap has 2 more elements 
                self.max_heap.push(self.min_heap.pop())
            else: # max_heap has 2 more elements
                self.min_heap.push(self.max_heap.pop())
            assert abs(len(self.min_heap) - len(self.max_heap)) < 2

print("Before streaming medians", MinHeap(), sep="\t")

b = StreamingMedian()
b.add_val(5)
b.add_val(100)

assert b.get_median() == 52.5

print("After streaming medians, for MaxHeap", MaxHeap(), sep='\t') # is empty
print("After streaming medians, for MinHeap", MinHeap(), sep='\t') # should be empty
print("After streaming medians, for MinHeap with input", MinHeap([]), sep="\t") # is empty
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The Problem

The problem was occurring because of how default arguments are calculated in python. They are computed the first time a function is called and afterwards the function is used with the originally calculated value. If the default value is mutable (as a list is) then this poses a problem.

So what was happening for the `MinHeap` was:

1. `MinHeap` initially created and the `l` parameter default argument was assigned to a memory address.
2. `StreamingMedian` modifies `MinHeap`'s `self.heap` which is the same as what `l` points to.
3. When `MinHeap` is called again, `l` already has a memory address and this memory address is used again and binded with `self.heap`.

This doesn't happen for `MaxHeap` because:

1. `MaxHeap` initially created and the `l` parameter default argument was assigned to a memory address.
2. `_invert_sign` creates a new list which is assigned to `self.heap`. The default argument `l` is never modified.
3. When `MaxHeap` is initialized again, `l` already has a memory address and is used again, but it was never modified and another copy is constructed so it will never be modified.

## The Solution

Instead of:

```
class MinHeap(object):

def __init__(self, l=[]):
    self.heap = l
    heapq.heapify(l)
```

We should use:

```
class MinHeap(object):

def __init__(self, l=None):
    if l is None:
        l = []
    self.heap = l
    heapq.heapify(l)
```

A similar change should be made for `MaxHeap`